# Dart: mapping a list of string into a string

Tags: dictionary, dart

I dont quite get the execution sequence when we use the map function in dart

For example code below (this example maybe trival, but I just want to illustrate my question)

This is trying to converting a list of titles into a string that contain all title

```
var moviesTitles = ['Inception', 'Heat', 'Spider Man'];

moviesTitles.map((title) => title).join('\n')
```

So, I am not sure which of my understanding are correct

1. first, the map function will apply (title) => title on each item and then consolidate them into a new list , then join them with \n

Or

2. the map function will apply (title) => title on each item and , in per loop, append it with \n ; then consolidate them into a string only at the end.
   Sequence is illustrated below

1.Inception + '\n'

2.Heat+ '\n'

3.Spider Man + '\n'

Finally, Inception + '\n' + Heat+ '\n' + Spider Man + '\n'

I found understanding no.2 makes more sense, but it seems the syntax showing .join after map doesn't match this logic

Comment: The `.map()` call is pointless in this case.  The code could be just `moviesTitles.join('\n')`.

Comment: i knew, as i stated in question, this example maybe trival, but I just want to illustrate my question which is the sequence of execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function is lazy. So, calling `titles.map((title) => title)` immediately creates a new `Iterable` which wraps the list `titles` and the function `(title) => title`.

Then you call `.join('\n')` on that iterable.
It's not specified exactly what that does, each platform can have its own implementation of `join`, but we know that it iterates over the iterable it's called on, by getting the `.iterator`, then calling `.moveNext()` and getting `.current` of that iterator until it has all the values of it.

Iterating the `titles.map(...)` iterable will iterate `titles`. Since `titles` is a list, that's probably optimized into just accessing the members by index in order. When the iterator is asked for a value (using `moveNext` and then `current`), it will get the next element of `titles` and call `(title) => title` with it, then provide that as its value of `current`. One by one, when they are asked for.

The `join` call gets those strings and combines them with `\n` strings in *some way*. Could be a `StringBuffer`, could be just a list, could be internal functionality that's not available to non-platform code (like writing directly into an allocated string). We may never know. (Spoiler, it's a [StringBuffer](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/iterable.dart#L354)).

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** first variant

According to the documentation:

> Iterable map(T Function(String) f)

Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the returned Iterable is not iterated over, the supplied function f will not be invoked. The transformed elements will not be cached. Iterating multiple times over the returned Iterable will invoke the supplied function f multiple times on the same element.

Methods on the returned iterable are allowed to omit calling f on any element where the result isn't needed. For example, elementAt may call f only once.

> String join([String separator = ""])

Converts each element to a String and concatenates the strings.

Iterates through elements of this iterable, converts each one to a String by calling Object.toString, and then concatenates the strings, with the separator string interleaved between the elements.